# Why is it illegal to put package-level defs/types/implicits at the root-level of a file?

Tags: scala, package

This question has been bugging me ever since I started using Scala. So here's my trail of thought:

1. Scala doesn't have the requirement, which Java has, that everything has to be in a class—this is a good thing!
2. Scala has functions, i.e. methods without a class/object
3. packages are objects, so if you define a class in a package, it'll go into the package object
4. some things have to be put into package objects explicitly, whereas some things don't—**WHY?**

I think it's just ugly to have to write:

```
package foo.bar

object `package` {
  type Foo = Bar
  def fact(n: Int): Int = ???
}
```

instead of just

```
package foo.bar

type Foo = Bar
def fact(n: Int): Int = ???
```

So: does anybody know when/why was it decided that it's better to require explicit wrapping with (the otherwise implicit) package objects? I'm constantly finding myself annoyed with the extra level of indent and boilerplate introduced by the obscure `object package` declaration, which is annoying just for the same reason this is annoying in Java:

```
class MyMath {
    public static int fact(int n) { ... }
}
```

Comment: don't know the true reasons, but package-object syntax encourage you to keep all definitions (remember, they will be visible package-wide) in one place (instead of being scattered all over the code base)

Comment: @om-nom-nom: but that's not entirely correct: you can have classes in the same package scattered around 1000 files if you like.

Comment: let's say I define function `x`, I may define it in a class (file) MyClass1 or MyClass2 or ... or MyClassN, all placed in `foo.bar` package and this function `x` will be visible everywhere in `foo.bar` from ... nowhere -- now it's quite hard to find it's definition place (yes, I know that we have grep, IDE's and so on). Don't get your last comment objections about classes.

Comment: @om-nom-nom: you can define classes into `package foo` from as many `.scala` files as you like; also, there's nothing enforcing the one-class-per-file convention, nor the convention that the file name should be the same as the class name, so then why, all of the sudden, are we enforcing `def`s, `type`s and `implicit`s to be in one place? Besides, that "one place" for the package object of package `foo.bar` can be `x123_hello.scala` in a folder called `i/love/bacon` anyway, talking of findability.